# Handling special action in pexpect module

Tags: python, cisco, pexpect

I am working on a Cisco device and I am using python's pexpect module to fetch some results in the Linux server. I give the following show command:
`sh cef resource detail location  0/RSP0/CPU0 | i "summary|CurrMode"`. When I am executing the command to get the result I am getting the following error:
`% Can't handle special action '|'. Quitting`. I am not able to understand what exactly is happening. Anyone please help me out. Thank you!

Comment: it doesn't understand the `|` (pipe) char obviously.  I note you're using it in two different contexts there: first to pipe into the `i` command, and thence inside the quotes as a string. Which one is raising the error?

Comment: the one in between summary and CurrMode.

Comment: maybe you need to escape it (usually a backslash)?

Comment: it isn't helping..I read on the following [link](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/FAQ.html) that for characters like pipe, we need to do something else, but I amd not able to relate it with my context.

Comment: It is easier to help you when you show us your code.